# node js resize all images in the folder using graphicsmagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am using nodejs packages (imagemagick and graphicsmagick) for image resize and image crop.
But how to resize all the images in the particular folder to another folder.

For example I am trying to convert all images in test folder to resize test1 folder.

```
var fs = require('fs'), gm = require('gm');

 gm('test/abcd.jpg').resizeExact(240, 240).write('test1/abcd.jpg', function(err) {
 if (err) {
 console.log(err);
 } else {
 console.log('done');
 }
 });
```

Anyone help for this.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? i need to convert all jpegs in one folder and save it to another folder as well. I have 100's of images

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to iterate through a directory of files with ImageMagick is to use the `mogrify` command like this:

```
mogrify -path resized -resize 1000x1000 *.png
```

which will take all the PNG files in the current directory and resize them and write the results into a subdirectory called `resized`.

I am no expert on `nodejs` but I don't believe the `mogrify` command exists in the port. There is a thing called `cadabra` but it looks old and disused to me - again I may be wrong. Link is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cadabra).

Else, you will need to walk the directory... [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7041638/2836621).